# why are multiple objects in my array being changed when only index is changed

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to make a game of chess in Java. I currently have a 8 x 8 2D array of "Squares" an object that contain a button and a "Piece" the pieces have a field called `hasMoved` which I am attempting to change inside of some logic in my button's action listener.

Before the below code I am testing whether or not the desired move is legal and if it is I "perform the move" where I update the old square to not have a piece and set the new squares piece equal to the old one. I also am attempting to update that piece to `hasMoved = true;` the column and row values are the values of the action listener set when I create them so if i press the bottom left square the action listeners column is 0 and the row is 7

```
boardManager.currentBoard.squaresOnBoard[column][row].occupiedPiece.hasMoved = true;
```

I was then printing and checking the `hasMoved` status of the other piece when I noticed that they were almost all set to true. I double checked that this is the only assignment operation i perform on this field in my entire program, I do call the value of it for some of my move logic but never assigning it to anything.

Here is a snippet of the code of the action listener for each button that is executed if the desired move is in the list of legal moves.

```
if(isLegalMove){
    //setting new icon to the icon of the old piece
    boardManager.currentBoard.squaresOnBoard[column][row].button.setIcon(selectedPieceIcon); 

    //setting new space to have the piece of the old space
    boardManager.currentBoard.squaresOnBoard[column][row].occupiedPiece = selectedPiece;
    boardManager.currentBoard.squaresOnBoard[column][row].occupiedPiece.hasMoved = true;

    System.out.println(boardManager.currentBoard.squaresOnBoard[column][row].occupiedPiece.hasMoved);

    // setting the old square to empty bc we moved
    boardManager.currentBoard.squaresOnBoard[selectedPieceColumn][selectedPieceRow].button.setIcon(null); 
    boardManager.currentBoard.squaresOnBoard[selectedPieceColumn][selectedPieceRow].occupiedPiece = null;
    boardManager.artificalIntelligence.performRandomLegalComputerMove();

    boardManager.currentBoard.printBoard();
    boardManager.moveGenerator.generateAllFullyLegalHumanMoves(boardManager.currentBoard);
    boardManager.selectedAPieceToMove = false;
}else{
    System.out.println("This is not a legal move for this piece.");
}
```

Why is more than just the index of the pressed button i.e. [column][row] changing during this action event? I am really confused at the nature of this.

Comment: I cannot see your declarations but do you have anything statically defined which shouldn't be?

Comment: Are your different `pieces` all pointing to the same object?

Comment: nope the only static fields or methods i create are for the color of each player set at the beginning of the game

Comment: Kinda trivial, but allow me to ask: "Do you reset the value of `hasMoved` in the other piece to `false`?" - Because it's not shown in the code.

Comment: This is why a decent [mcve] is needed for questions like these. Please provide one as code-formatted text with this question.

Comment: @brso05 wow i think you're right, it looks like i was generating the intial rows of pawns by making an object and setting the same reference as opposed a new piece ill ttry that now

Comment: @Izruo well the value of the old "Square" we moved from has an occupiedPiece field which i set to null in the above code so i just keep all of the starting piece objects and move them around my Board object which is really just a Square[8][8]

Comment: @Brendan We are checking on a member variable of the `Piece` class, so a  `Field` and anything associated to it doesn't matter here (unless it modifies the memeber variable). However, if bsro already named your problem, just forget my comment; no need use too moch effort here. ;)